# How to a include a timer in my program

Tags: javascript, java

I want to write a program that checks email every 5 minutes and notifies me when I have new email. I am new to programming

Comment: If you need Javascript: `setInterval(checkEmail, 5000)` And add your code to check email in `checkEmail` function

Answer (score 0):

Use `cron` jobs. Just write your program to check mails & use the schedulers like cron jobs or windows scheduler

If you are using web application, use time interval in javascript & send the request through `AJAX`.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of timer you can use camel.

Component Mail of camel would help you to achieve it. Also, notifing with camel would be extremally easy.

Answer (score 0):

@kganetso
Try this example to check ur mail every 5 mints

```
fucntion checkMail(){
       $.ajax({
       type:"GET",
       url:"ur_php_page_url",
       onSuccess:function (){
          //write a msg and append it where u want 
          setTimeout('checkMail()',50000);
       }
       });
}
```

btw is this question was for mobile app or for browser ?

Comment: Please consider editing your post to add more explanation about what your code does and why it will solve the problem. An answer that mostly just contains code (even if it's working) usually wont help the OP to understand their problem.